# .htaccess RewriteRule with slash in url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

What do I need to do to the following rewrite rule with slash in the url?

`http://www.website.com/p/EQUITY+INVESTMENT+CORP%2FGA`

to

`http://www.website.com/test.php?name=EQUITY+INVESTMENT+CORP%2FGA`

I tried the following way but not working.

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*) /test.php?name=$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule is fine but [`%2F` isn't allowed in URIs by Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes). To allow `%2F` to be encoded to `/` you need to add:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

in your `<VirtualHost...>` section or in global context of your Apache config.